# python - Efficiently parsing flattened strings into nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, parsing, marshalling

I'm obtaining a list of directories and items from a proprietary database.  The lists can also be enormous containing thousands of views and a vareity of nesting. Example of list:

```
"MIPK",
"MIPK\/CM.toroidal",
"MIPK\/CM.Supervoid",
"MIPK\/DORAS",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/CRUDE",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/CRUDE\/CM.forest",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/CRUDE\/CM.benign",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/CRUDE\/CM.dunes",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/COMMODITIES",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/COMMODITIES\/CRUDE",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/COMMODITIES\/CRUDE\/CM.tangeant",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/COMMODITIES\/CRUDE\/CM.astral",
"MIPK\/DORAS\/COMMODITIES\/CRUDE\/CM.forking"
```

Directories are upper-case separated with `\/` and mixed case represents items.

My current returned JSon is like this:

```
    {
    "contents": [{
        "root_path": "MIPK",
        "root_name": "MIPK",
        "directories": [{
            "subd_name": "DORAS",
            "subd_path": "MIPK.DORAS"
        }],
        "views": [{
                "view_name": "CM.toroidal"
            },
            {
                "view_name": "CM.Supervoid"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "root_path": "MIPK.DORAS",
        "root_name": "DORAS",
        "directories": [{
                "subd_name": "CRUDE",
                "subd_path": "MIPK.DORAS.CRUDE"
            },
            {
                "subd_name": "COMMODITIES",
                "subd_path": "MIPK.DORAS.COMMODITIES"
            }
        ],
        "views": []
    }, {
        "root_path": "MIPK.DORAS.CRUDE",
        "root_name": "CRUDE",
        "directories": [],
        "views": [{
                "view_name": "CM.forest"
            },
            {
                "view_name": "CM.benign"
            },
            {
                "view_name": "CM.dunes"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "root_path": "MIPK.DORAS.COMMODITIES",
        "root_name": "COMMODITIES",
        "directories": [{
            "subd_name": "CRUDE",
            "subd_path": "MIPK.DORAS.COMMODITIES.CRUDE"
        }],
        "views": []

    }, {
        "root_path": "MIPK.DORAS.COMMODITIES.CRUDE",
        "root_name": "CRUDE",
        "directories": [],
        "views": [{
                "view_name": "CM.tangeant"
            },
            {
                "view_name": "CM.astral"
            },
            {
                "view_name": "CM.forking"
            }
        ]
    }]

}
```

Current code:

```
import logging
import copy
import time

def fetch_resources(input_resources_list):
    '''
    :return: Json list of dictionaries each dictionary element containing:
    Directory name, directory path, list of sub-directories, list of views

    resource_list is a flattened list produced by a database walk function
    '''

    start = time.time()
    resources = {
        'contents': [{}]
    }

    for item in input_resources_list:
        # Parsing list into usable pieces
        components = item.rsplit('\\', 1)

        if len(components) == 1:
            # Handles first element
            root_dict = {'root_path': components[0],
                         'root_name': components[-1],
                         'directories': [],
                         'views': []
                         }
            resources['contents'][0].update(root_dict)
        else:
            #  Enumerate resources in list so search by key value can be done and then records can be appended.
            for ind, content in enumerate(copy.deepcopy(resources['contents'])):

                if resources['contents'][ind]['root_path'] == components[0]:
                    # Directories are upper case, adds a new entry if
                    if clean_item.isupper() :
                        root_dict = {'root_path': components[0],
                                     'root_name': components[-1],
                                     'directories': [],
                                     'views': []
                                     }
                        resources['contents'].append(root_dict)
                        sub_dict = {'subd_path': components[0],
                                    'subd_name': components[-1]}
                        resources['contents'][ind]['directories'].append(sub_dict)
                    elif clean_item.isupper() == False :
                        resources['contents'][ind]['views'] \
                            .append({'view_name':components[-1]})
    print 'It took {}'.format((time.time() - start)*1000) 
    return resources
```

This works fine on small workloads (circa 100-500), however not at the target workloads of 000's.

1. How can I optimise the method for time?
2. Currently the enumerate loop is rebuilt for every item in the input list in order to search by the `root_path` key values.  Is there an easier way to search the list of dicts for key value and append entries to that entries directories and views list?

Comment: Instead of using nested comprehensions, write it with for loop statements and it probably won’t look as messy, or be as hard to get right. Not everything has to be made as dense as humanly possible.

Comment: But meanwhile, it would probably be easier to generate what you want directly on the walk, rather than using the walk to build up a list of strings and then trying to parse those strings afterward.

Comment: Also, you’re storing directories as a dict if they contain subdirectories, but as a list if they include files. What should happen if a directory includes both? Is that an error?

Comment: In response to your last comment they can contain both files and directories... added an explanation to the output format.  How should the structure look if this is the case?

Comment: You've completely changed the structure you're asking for. And, meanwhile, the structure you show here is totally different from the one you asked for in a comment on my answer. Whatever format you want, you can build with the basic structure that's in my answer, but of course some of the details will be different, and I can't give you code that can be copied and pasted and handle everything you could possibly ask for.

Comment: I've updated the comment and this question to more accurately reflect what I want and also to make the desired format more regular as you mentioned there were inconsistencies.  I'm not looking for code for every case just how it would be done for the above. Do appreciate the information you have provided so far though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve thrown away a lot of information in building these strings. For example, when you see `MIPK\/DORAS`, there’s no way to know whether it’s a file (which should just be a string in the parent directory’s list), a leaf directory (which should be a list in the parent directory’s dict), or an intermediate directory (which should be a dict in the parent directory’s dict). The best you can do (without a quadratic nested search) is guess, and then change it later if you guessed wrong.

Also, sometimes your intermediate directories don’t even show up on their own, but only appear as components of later paths, but other times they do appear. So sometimes the “guess” that you have to fix will be the directory not existing at all.

And finally, your desired format is ambiguous if, e.g., any directly can contain both files and directories (should it be a dict or a list), or nothing at all (should it be an empty dict, an empty list, or just a string?).

However, things seem to be in sorted order, and the ambiguous cases don’t seem to actually show up. If we can rely on both of these, we can tell whether something is a directory by just seeing if it’s a prefix or the next entry. Then we can just read the leaves and put them into a collection of a strings inside a list inside 0 or more nested dicts.

So, first, we want to iterate adjacent pairs of paths, to make it easier to do that “is it a prefix of the next value?” check:

```
output = {}

it1, it2 = itertools.tee(paths)
next(it2)
pairs = itertools.zip_longest(it1, it2, fillvalue='')
for path, nextpath in pairs:
    if nextpath.startswith(path):
        continue
```

Now, we know `path` is a leaf, so we need to find the list to append it to, creating one if needed, which may mean recursively creating dicts along the way:

```
components = path.split(r'\/')
d = output
for component in components[:-2]:
    d = d.setdefault(component, {})
d.setdefault(components[-2], []).append(components[-1])
```

I haven’t tested this, but it should do the right thing for non-ambiguous input, but raise some kind of exception if any directory includes both files and subdirs, or any top-level directory includes files, or any of the other ambiguous cases (except for empty directories, which will be treated the same as files).

Sure, this is kind of ugly, but that’s inherent in parsing an ugly format that relies on lots of special-case rules to handle what would otherwise be ambiguous.

Comment: Updated the question to more accurately reflect what I want. Each directory will contain the following fields: `name` `directories` `views`. Where directories contains sub directories and views just contains the `id` of the views.  So how would the dictionary be assigned to those headings?  Can you also explain the flow of the code you provided?  I'm not following